# circle progress bar for player

Tags: actionscript-3, trigonometry

Maybe the problem and simple, but not for me, with trigonometry was always tight.
This should be a round progress bar for the player.
There is a circle, you need to calculate the angle from 0 to a point where the touch / click occurred.

I found this:

```
var degr:Number = (getAngle(centerX, centerY, touchX, touchY) * 180 / Math.PI);

private function getAngle (x1:Number, y1:Number, x2:Number, y2:Number):Number
{
    var dx:Number = x2 - x1;
    var dy:Number = y2 - y1;
    return Math.atan2(dy,dx);
}
```

but it outputs on one side of from 0 to 180, on the other between -180 and 0. need from 0 to 360.

Please share with us his thoughts. Who can faced with, can anyone have a solution ready, I will be grateful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because atan2 return  positive pi and negative pi, 
try following

```
var degr:Number = (getAngle(centerX, centerY, touchX, touchY ) );

function getAngle (x1:Number, y1:Number, x2:Number, y2:Number ):Number
{
    var radian:Number = Math.atan2(y2 - y1,x2 - x1);
    var degree:Number = radian*( 180/Math.PI);
    return  ( degree > 0 ? degree  : ( 360 + degree));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what is needed!